# RecyclerView item to affect the value of a TextView outside the RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, switchcompat

I have an `Activity` which contains 2 `TextView` shows a numerical value and there is a `RecyclerView` below them, the `RecyclerView` has a `TextView` with a numerical value and a `SwitchCompat`, I want if the user turned the `SwitchCompat` to `ON` the number in the `TextView` inside the `RecyclerView` to be added to the number at the `TextView` outside the `RecyclerView` and if the `SwitchCompat` is switched to `OFF` the number is subtracted from the number in the outside `TextView`.

I tried to pass the `TextView` to the `RecyclerViewAdapter` and use it in the Adapter Class but the error happens that it works fine for the first time but when scrolling random numbers to be added and subtracted from the `TextView` ,, the following is my code :

> AdapterClass.java

```java
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ExpensesListAdapterViewHolder holder, int position) {
...
holder.switchComp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    eList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setmFlag(isChecked);

                if (isChecked) {
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(eList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getmExpenseName())) {
                        // switch is on + Increase Budget

                        totalBudget.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(totalBudget.getText().toString())+eList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getmAmount()));
                        totalRemaining.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(totalRemaining.getText().toString())+eList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getmAmount()));

                    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(eList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getmI_B_Name())) {
                        // switch is on + expense

                        totalExpense.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(totalExpense.getText().toString())+eList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getmAmount()));
                        totalRemaining.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(totalRemaining.getText().toString())-eList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getmAmount()));

                    }

                } else {

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(eList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getmExpenseName())) {
                        // switch is off + increase budget

                        totalBudget.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(totalBudget.getText().toString())-eList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getmAmount()));
                        totalRemaining.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(totalRemaining.getText().toString())-eList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getmAmount()));


                    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(eList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getmI_B_Name())) {
                        // switch is off + expense

                        totalExpense.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(totalExpense.getText().toString())-eList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getmAmount()));
                       totalRemaining.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(totalRemaining.getText().toString())+eList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getmAmount()));

                    }
                }
```

Comment: You need to make changes in the data set and then notify the adapter ..

Comment: but i am not changing values of the recyclerview ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a function to update the textview values like everytime one view is checked:

```
   @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ExpensesListAdapterViewHolder holder, int position) {


    holder.switchComp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            eList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setmFlag(isChecked);

            updateTotalValues();

        }
    }
    }
}
```

your update function should look like (replace object to your real objects name):

```
public void updateTotalValues(){
Double sumRemaining = 0d;
Double sumBudget = 0d;
Double sumExpense = 0d;

for(eList e : List<Object>){
    boolean isChecked = e.getmFlag;

    if (isChecked) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(e.getmExpenseName())) {
            // switch is on + Increase Budget
            sumBudget+= e.getmAmount();
            sumRemaining+= e.getmAmount();

        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(e.getmI_B_Name())) {
            // switch is on + expense
            sumExpense+=e.getmAmount();
            sumRemaining+= e.getmAmount();
        }

    } else {

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(e.getmExpenseName())) {
            // switch is off + increase budget
            sumBudget+= e.getmAmount();
            sumRemaining-= e.getmAmount();

        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(e.getmI_B_Name())) {
            // switch is off + expense
            sumExpense-=e.getmAmount();
            sumRemaining+= e.getmAmount();

        }
}

totalBudget.setText(sumBudget);
totalRemaining.setText(sumRemaining);
totalExpense.setText(sumExpense);
```

}

Comment: unfortunately same error happens, dummy numbers added without pressing anything just with scrolling

Comment: Could you try to calculate separately?